# 'expo'/'react-native'/'react-native-render-html'/'react-navigation' dependency is not installed

Tags: react-native, expo, yarnpkg, create-react-app

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && yarn install
```

I tried a lot of times to reinstall these dependncies, but everytime when I run

```
exp start -c
```

I have following warnings

```
01:22:43 [exp] Warning: 'expo' dependency is not installed.
01:22:43 [exp] Warning: 'react-native' dependency is not installed.
01:22:43 [exp] Warning: 'react-native-render-html' dependency is not installed.
```

this is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "Real300",
  "version": "0.7.2",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.58.0",
    "flow-remove-types": "^1.2.3",
    "jest-expo": "^26.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
  },
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch",
    "prepublish": "yarn run build",
    "flow": "flow"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "buffer": "^5.0.8",
    "expo": "26.0.0",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.4.19",
    "install": "^0.10.1",
    "native-base": "^2.3.2",
    "npm": "^5.5.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-26.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-camera-roll-picker": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-dimension": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.1.15",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.8.5",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.18.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
    "react-native-material-cards": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-material-ui": "^1.14.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.257",
    "react-native-render-html": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "4.0.0-beta.22",
    "react-native-sglistview": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-tab-view": "0.0.70",
    "react-native-viewpager": "^0.2.13",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.8",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "sudo": "^1.0.3",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.11"
  }
}
```

My project have ejected with expo kit and I am following instruction of the eject screen. It was working fine before ejection but now I cannot let my code run.

I build my codes in Xcode and it was successfully. I can run simulator but I can see nothing from it, just white screen. Expect I have a red banner on the bottom with those "dismiss""reload""copy""more info". I try to copy but nothing goes to my clipboard.

the repo of my ejection is:
1. npm run eject
2. choose expoKit
3. waiting for it to eject
4. updated expo sdk to 26
5. change react native to expo fork
6. pod install

did I miss something?

Comment: The problem could be related to the fact that updating Expo after detach is a little more involved than just updating the npm modules. You will need to also update the native code as well.

Comment: @EvanBacon Should I run pod install or pod update again to update native code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case closed.

I have to update yarn to the newest version and npm is not gonna work.

after update yarn to 1.6, everything is good now.